# Regular expression for getting number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string as:-

```
String -----> Result I need
 
1.25 acres ---> 1.25
125 acres ----> 125 
1,25 sqft ----> 125 
12,5 foot ----> 125
```

I am currently using :- `.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)` but it is getting `1` for `1,25` and `12` for `12,5`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `.match(/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?/)`

Comment: If the input string is `12,5`, you'll note that the character sequence `125` does not occur in the input string.   So `match` is not suitable for what you're doing.  You might look into replacing characters that are not `0` through `9` or a `.` with an empty string with something like `.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')`

Comment: I am not using it for input field, I'm trying to scrape the website data which has strings like this, and I need to get numbers from the large set of array I've

Comment: So, `.match(/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?/g)` will do, or `.match(/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*/g)`.

Comment: Remove commas first: [`str.replace(/\b,\b/,'').match(/\d+\.?\d*/)[0]`](https://tio.run/##TYzLDsIgFET3fMXdAYpgTZqYNNWVX1Fc3FLqI1QqkG6M347oyt2cycy544LRhNucNss@Z2cTxBQitNDRSu5qQBNspIJW/1kUiM8x/XpR03NDyPcmRx9OaK6MFeLQHuBFAKZiKyyDnR0ay5Tuhe6VoJTLCVOZKz2stTzqYaV4ty02AOMf0Tsrnb@wiTfkzYHk/AE)

Answer (score 1):

You could also remove the first `,` you encounter and then use `parseFloat`. Something like this:

`parseFloat(str.replace(",",""))`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
str.match(/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*/g)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/R13cby/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [.,]                     any character of: '.', ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
```

**JavaScript code snippet**:

```js
const str = `1.25 acres
125 acres
1,25 sqft
12,5 foot`
console.log(str.match(/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*/g))
```